# Writing the build.ps1 console output to a specific log file

Tags: powershell, logging, cakebuild

I am using cake script to build my application. While the build process all the logging informations are displayed in the console. I want to write all the console output into a specific log file in the same path where the build.ps1 is located.

Build process is like, from gitlab-ci a particular bat file will be called. That bat file will get necessary build informations and build.ps1 will be called as below.

> call start /wait /i cmd /c powershell.exe -Command %PSFILE_PATH% --rebrand="app_name"
> pause

[PSFILE_PATH - will have the build.ps1 file path with file name.
eg: "F:\Build\app_name\build.ps1"]

**Info: I have tried using ".\build.ps1 > output.log" this works while running the build in my local machine. But, in my application build process(via gitlab-ci runner) I'm unable to use this command.**

Please suggest a way(other than ".\build.ps1 > output.log") to log all the outputs printed in the console into a file while running build.ps1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your call look like for the build scheduler, and which scheduler are you using?

Comment: I am running my build via gitlab-ci. from there will be executing a specific bat file which in turn calls the build.ps1 with necessary arguments.

Comment: In that case, it should work with the `>` operator. You just have to make sure to have it write to a file that actually gets persisted, so for example save it as an artifact.

Comment: Btw you can tell the gitlab runner to use powershell too.

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing the answer, There is a situation like i cannot use "./build.ps1 > filename.log" in my gitlab runner [Where i cannot tell runner to use powershell directly]. Is there any way to log inside build.ps1 or somewhere other than using "./build.ps1 > filename.log"

Comment: Well you can of course put single log lines into the script like `echo MyLogText > output.log`. When you put the whole `call...` command into your local console, does it generate the output you want? Maybe you could route that to output.log instead.

Comment: Setup(ctx =>
{
 // Executed BEFORE the first task.
 Information("Running tasks...");
 var commitMessage = GetCommitMessage();
 Information("Commit Message : " + commitMessage);
 Information("today_date : " + today_date);
 Information("msBuildPathX64 : " + msBuildPathX64);
 Information("git_path : " + git_path);
 Information("rebrandName : " + rebrandName);
});

This is the setup task of cake script, here the "Information()" logs the string to a console output. My expectation is like, i want those console output as a log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can persist this information from the Gitlab-ci build by saving it as an artifact. Just add this to your job's description in the gitlab-ci.yml:

```
artifacts:
  name: 'Build output' # or whatever
  when: always # or on_success/on_failure depending on your use case
  paths:
    - output.log
  expire_in: 1 day # or 4 hours or however long you want to keep it stored
```

This way you can look at the output.log file via pipelines > your pipeline > artifacts.